# Capture result of HTML5 FileReader to a variable using promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, base64, filereader

I have an Angular 4 application where I am reading an image & trying to pass the base64 string to another variable - however I am having an issue due to the async nature of this - the `image.src` is empty and therefore the value has passed correctly to the image object?

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let image = new Image();
    var promise = this.getBase64(fileObject, this.processImage());
    promise.then(function(base64) {
        console.log(base64);    // outputs string e.g 'data:image/jpeg;base64,........'
    });

    image.src = base64; // how to get base64 string into image.src var here??          
}

/**
 * get base64 string from supplied file object
 */
public getBase64(file, onLoadCallback) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function() { resolve(reader.result); };
        reader.onerror = reject;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}

public processImage() {

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue you got is `base64` is variable, scoped in callback function of `.then()`. To get it correct just do this:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let image = new Image();
    var promise = this.getBase64(fileObject, this.processImage());
    promise.then(function(base64) {    // base64 variable is scoped to this function only.
        console.log(base64);    // outputs string e.g 'data:image/jpeg;base64,........'

        image.src = base64;
    });
}
```

Comment: do I need to add anything to the processImage()? Currently I get a 'type {} not assignable to string on the `image.src = base64` line in the code? Promises confuse the hell out of me :)

Comment: Why to use callback when using promises?